# Altering labels in distance matrix

Tags: r, label

I have a labelled number list and I am hoping to shorten all the labels in the list.

I have a similar line which does this successfully for row names:

```
> rownames(embu) <- paste(substring(rownames(embu),7,22),sep="")
```

However this does not transfer to labels

```
> labels(cell.dist) <- (paste(substring(labels(cell.dist),8,23),sep=""))
Error in labels(cell.dist) <- (paste(substring(labels(cell.dist), 8, 23),  : 
  could not find function "labels<-"
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Maybe it's `names`, not `labels`, the function you are looking for. What package does `labels` come from?

Comment: names(cell.dist) comes back null, although I've realised my error and fixed it (see answer below), thanks for taking a look though!

Answer (score 0):

Realised my error, did not realise the object was a distance matrix (made with "as.dist" from some third party code), fixed with this:

```
labels <- paste(substring(labels(cell.dist),8,23),sep="")
cell.dist <- dist_setNames(cell.dist, labels)
```